# One-to-one and onto linear transformations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Is there any way to know whether a linear transformation is one-to-one or onto just looking at its associated matrix?
I mean, without doing calculations, and given a matrix asocciated to a linear transformation, can I realize if the transformation is one-to-one or onto?

Comment: No. You need to look at the row reduced echelon form. Once you know where the pivots are, then you'll be able to tell if the map is injective and/or surjective.

Comment: For non-square matrices, you may sometimes see immediately that the linear transformation *cannot* be one-to-one or *cannot* be onto ...

Comment: "Without doing calculations..."  Well, with *minimal* calculations you can learn a great deal about a matrix.  For the special case of square matrices, the [invertible-matrix theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InvertibleMatrixTheorem.html) gives a list of several equivalent necessary and sufficient conditions for whether or not a matrix is invertible and is a highly important list of information to keep stored in your toolbox.

Comment: That being said, one doesn't need to go so far as to look at the *reduced* row echelon form, but you can merely look at the row echelon form by itself without going through the additional steps.  You should be able to tell quite a bit by looking at the REF of the matrix or if the matrix is already in REF (*e.g. by being upper-triangular*).